# Make bower dependency management optional in each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, bower, dependency-management

I have a non-single-page website that should have a light homepage. I use angularjs and some other javascript libraries in my site but I don't want include them in my homepage, but bower automatically include all bower components in all pages. Is there any way that I tell bower just include jquery and bootstrap in homepage and include all dependencies in other pages?

P.S. I am using gulp to deploy my project.

Answer (score 0):

Bower is just for management of libraries. I would suggest you to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) for file and module loading.